# Error handling in php functions without crashes

Tags: php, function, if-statement, error-handling

I want to handle an error in my PHP function without crashing my whole script.

First it pushes this error:

> Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in E:\amir\1magazine\tools\xampp\htdocs\CairoHash\assests\plugins\content_handling.php on line 74

I know what the error is for, but I want to continue without crashing my script.

I tried `if` but it didn't work as I hoped.

```
$count = count($selector);
$order = substr($order, 0 , -1);
switch ($count)
{
    case 1:
        $i = $html->find($selector);                 
        break;
    case 2:
        $i = $html->find($selector[0],$selector[1]);
        break;
    case 3:
        /*  ln 74 ->>> */      $i = $html->find($selector[0],$selector[1])->$selector[2];
        break;
}
if(isset($i))
{
    return $i;
}
```

This code is supposed to get the `$i` variable but I need to say if it didn't work then don't crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check earlier if something is set.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

on line 74 means that `find($selector[0],$selector[1])` is not returning an object. So you can do your checks there instead.

```
case 3:           
    $x = $html->find($selector[0],$selector[1]);
    if ($x) $i = $x->$selector[2];
    break;
```

That should fix this specific error, but you may encounter the same problem for other cases, so you should verify that `find()` was successful in every `case` before using its result.